# Java - Create a "many-to-many"-relation between 2 classes

Tags: java, many-to-many

I will try to explain my problem based on an example:

We have one class called "**Car**", and one called "**Worker**".

One car gets build by multiple workers, while one worker has built multiple cars.

**My question is:**

How do I create some kind of "many-to-many"-relationship between those two classes, like commonly used with databases, WITHOUT importing any library except for
the java.lang.* and java.io.* packages, which means that "List" is thereby excluded, because it is in java.util.*

Thanks in advance :)

---

***Edit for further explaination:***

In databbases, you normally have a third table to split this "m-t-m"-relationship, so I thought at something like this on my picture. 
[image]
Would this be possible?

Comment: Take a leaf out of the graph database design book and create named entities to represent the relationships. That way you just have lists of relationships - like an adjacency list. Although whether that's sensible really depends on what queries you want to run against your data.

Comment: If you don't want to use third party libraries like spring-data  you should handle it by your own! It means that you should have list of other side object in the class(better to use set) and then fill them with custom queries.

Comment: If I understood your problem and my comment help you tell me to post it as an answer.

Comment: No I´m sry :( 
I edited my post, so you hopefully understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, in this case lists would be the best choice, but if you cannot use them, you could use arrays, something like this:

```
class Car {  
   private Worker[] builtBy;
   ...  
}

class Worker {  
   private Car[] carsBuilt;
   ...  
}
```

However, the main disadvantage is that arrays are fixed-size so if you need to add more elements to the array than the initially allocated amount, you would have to create a new one and copy the contents there.

Comment: Yeah I already thought about this, but shouldn´t I have a third class where I insert both objects? Or do I think to much like in databases?

Comment: @freedome97 you're thinking like in databases. But the answer is: it depends. Sometimes the cars should know about thir workers. Sometimes the workers needs to know about their cares. Sometimes they don't need to know anything about each other and some other class should handle the associations. In this case, the third case is probably more appropriate, yes. In a typical company building cars, you don't go to the car to know which workers have worked on it, and you don't go to a worker to know which care it has built.